# How to display a Firebase Auth error on signUp method?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

**I can't find a way to display if the user was created successfully or not.
I've tried to use if(errorToast!=null) but it didn't work.**

```
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
   var errorToast = error;
   M.toast({html: error});  
   if (errorToast === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
     M.toast({html: 'Outra conta já existe com esse Email'});  
   }
   else if (errorToast == 'auth/weak-password') {
     M.toast({html: 'Senha muito fraca'});  
   }
   else{
     M.toast({html: 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso'});
     sendEmailVerification();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns a promise containing a `firebase.auth.UserCredential`, so you should use `then()`, as follows:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass)
.then(function(userCredential) {
  // SUCCESS!! -> Do whatever you want
  // e.g. print the user to the console
  console.log(userCredential.user);
})
.catch(function(error) {
   // ERROR!! -> show the error, as you are already doing
   var errorToast = error;
   M.toast({html: error});  
   if (errorToast === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
     M.toast({html: 'Outra conta já existe com esse Email'});  
   }
   else if (errorToast == 'auth/weak-password') {
     M.toast({html: 'Senha muito fraca'});  
   }
})
```

See these pages for more explanations on how promises (and the `then()` method) work: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-promises or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise